# In scala, how to make inner type of an abstract type invariant to different instances?

Tags: scala, singleton, inner-classes

In some cases I would like to use inner type as an alternative of generic type, e.g. In the following case, instead of defining `Dependent[T <: BaseType]`, I define it like this:

```
abstract class BaseType {

  type N
  def create(v: Int): N

  class Dependent(val n: N) {

    def +(other: Dependent) = new Dependent(create(n.hashCode() + n.hashCode()))
  }
}

object BaseType {

  class Aggregator[T <: BaseType](val seq: Seq[T#Dependent]) {

    def result() = seq.reduce(_ + _)
  }
}
```

Obviously this won't compile because `Dependent` is now an Inner class, and different `Dependent` created under different instances of BaseType are not interoperable with each other. (BTW The following compilation error will be thrown)

```
Error:(15, 35) type mismatch;
 found   : T#Inner
 required: _33.Inner where val _33: T
    def result() = seq.reduce(_ + _)
```

However this problem should have a trivial solution in scala, because in java such task can be easily accomplished by:

```
static class Dependent { ...
```

It make no sense to have longer code in scala than java. An immediate analogy in scala would be to add an enforced rule in BaseType, which requires all its implementations to be object/singleton rather than class. However I haven't seen such feature.

So the question is, what is the SHORTEST way to do the same thing that can be easily done in java?

**UPDATE** apparently I wasn't quite clear about my intention, What I want is not using class `Dependent` as is, but to extend BaseType such that `BaseType` serves as a type parameter for `Dependent`, e.g. If I define 2 objects:

```
  object Sub1 extends BaseType {
    override type N = Long
    override def create(v: Int): N = v.toLong
  }
  object Sub2 extends BaseType {
    override type N = Double
    override def create(v: Int): N = v.toDouble
  }
```

Then both `+` sign and `Aggregator` can be used on 2 Dependent only if they are from the same object, which means this will succeed:

```
  assert(
    new Aggregator(
      Seq(
        new Sub1.Dependent(1),
        new Sub1.Dependent(2)
      )).result() == new Sub1.Dependent(1) +
      new Sub1.Dependent(2)
  )
```

yet this will fail:

```
  assert(
    new Aggregator(
      Seq(
        new Sub1.Dependent(1),
        new Sub2.Dependent(2)
      )).result() == new Sub1.Dependent(1) +
      new Sub2.Dependent(2)
  )
```

because 2 Dependent instances are of different types, however with the latest scala compiler even the first one will fail, because by the time Aggregator is defined it doesn't know `T <: BaseType` is a singleton.

Comment: There are definitely things that are intentionally more verbose in Scala than in Java, such as casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because in java such task can be easily accomplished by:
>
> ```
> static class Dependent { ...
> ```

No, it doesn't accomplish the task, because this `Dependent` can't use `N` (even if it's a type parameter of `BaseType`). You'd need `static class Dependent<N>`, and the Scala equivalent is

```
object BaseType {
  class Dependent[N]
}
```

It's true this is slightly longer than Java if you don't already have a companion object, but it's just not a requirement in Scala design that it can do anything that Java can with shorter code (or at all, really).

If you want

> Then both + sign and Aggregator can be used on 2 Dependent only if they are from the same object, which means this will succeed

this can be done:

```
class Aggregator[T <: BaseType with Singleton](val seq: Seq[T#Dependent]) {
  def result() = seq.reduce(_ + _)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you want, probably you had over-simplified your real problem.
But, in case not, would not this solve your problem?

```
sealed trait BaseType[N] {
  def create(v: Int): N
}

object BaseType {
  final implicit val LongBase: BaseType[Long] = new BaseType[Long] {
    override def create(v: Int): Long = v.toLong
  }

  final implicit val DoubleBase: BaseType[Double] = new BaseType[Double] {
    override def create(v: Int): Double = v.toDouble
  }

  final class Aggregator[N : BaseType](val seq: Seq[Depedent[N]]) {
    def result: Depedent[N] = seq.reduce(_ + _)
  }
}

final class Depedent[N](val n: N)(implicit base: BaseType[N]) {
  def + (that: Depedent[N]): Depedent[N] =
    new Depedent(base.create(this.n.hashCode + that.n.hashCode))
}
```

If this does not satisfy your problem, please leave a comment clarifying why it does not.